# php strtotime +2.5 hours bug?

Tags: php, strtotime

Having some unexpected behaviour with strtotime:

```
$d = '2.5';                                   // i.e. hours
$t = '2014-03-20 08:30:00';                   // mysql datetime
$ut = strtotime($t);                          // value: 1395297000
$s = $d * 60 * 60;                            // duration in seconds: 9000
$plusHrs = strtotime($t.' +'.$d.' hours');    // value: 1395315000
$plusSec = strtotime($t.' +'.$s.' seconds');  // value: 1395306000
```

Expected behaviour would be that $plusHrs = $plusSec. This happens regardless of what date is input, which means it's not a daylight saving issue.

Is this a bug? (PHP v5.3.14)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't a bug. [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) expects integer values in [relative](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) format. Thus, your `+2.5` hours would be treated as `"+2 GMT"` **and then** `"+5"` hours and dot would be just ignored. You can change it to comma or even delete as well - result won't change since, again, only integers are parsed. So, such statement will be treated as relative hours addition with respect of GMT offset:

```
//this is the same things:
//and they mean set timesone to GMT+2 & add 5 hours:
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now +2.5 hours'));
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now +2,5 hours'));
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now +2 5 hours'));
```

So, for example, `+1.5 hours` will do `add 5 hours for time in GMT +1`. That means, end result *will depend* of current timezone since initial timestamp will be set to current timezone (it's `now` in sample above).

Comment: Well that's not entirely true... put var_dumps around each of those lines and you'll see what I mean. The first 3 statements will add 5 hours, not 7 hours.

Comment: Well, that's tested, it's giving same 4 rows for me. I'll check what's about PHP versions

Comment: @geoidesic Added the point. It's not `+7 hours` (well, not in all timezones). It's little bit complicated.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this for hours `2.5`

```
$plusHrs = strtotime($t.' + 2 hours 30 minutes');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$plusHrs = strtotime($t.' +'.$d.' hours');    
$plusSec = strtotime($t.' +'.$s.' seconds'); 

These two are different, $s = $d * 60 * 60 while $d = '2.5.
```

Comment: What do you mean "different"? Natively, 2.5*60*60 seconds _is the same_ as 2.5 hours

Comment: If you mean .5 as 30 mins, that's a different thing